# Oracle Function to extract first / last value of code that with multiple series

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I'm having difficulties finding a way to extract the first and last values for a code in a series that can occur multiple times in a day.  Example, table data agents schedule can have breaks, lunch and other codes such as coach and ect.  I need to pull the first and last value for each coaching session for each agent per day.  I've attached pic of table data and expected output.

When I use last and first value functions, it wants to group all of the coaching as one instead of two for the example.  This is where I'm having the issue.

PIC example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxQAo.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question and share simple data/expected as text instead of images

Comment: you need to show all table DDL and sample data, expected output, sql executed as text and a [mcve]  Take the [tour] and read [ask]

Comment: I apologize.  I'll go back and redo.  Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (START as column name will not work, I changed to STRT)

```
SELECT * FROM DATA
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
PARTITION BY id, code
ORDER BY strt, stop
MEASURES first(strt) AS strt, MAX(stop) AS stop
PATTERN( merged* a )
DEFINE
  merged AS stop = NEXT(strt)
)
WHERE code= 'Co'
;
```

Comment: This worked great !!  I will make sure to put in table and code snippets going forward.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this looks like a very powerful feature and a perfect match for this case.